# iOS url scheme to open specific youtube page in youtube app

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, youtube

Is there anyway to use an iOS URL Scheme to open the YouTube to a particular user's profile I've tried youtube://user/myusername but that did not seem to work.

Comment: youtube://user/<desired username> works for me.

Comment: looks like this was recently added. excellent news. do you happen to know how to get to the videos page (as opposed to activity)?

Comment: To open a youtube channel, use `youtube://channel/<channel-id>`. I just tested and it works. (Youtube app version 2.5.1)

Comment: youtube://user/<desired username> was working, but no longer works. I believe youtube://channel/<channel-id> no longer works either. Any new ideas?

Answer (score 5):

To open a Youtube page in Youtube app (if it's installed on the device)
you can check whether the device can open the page:

```
// URL scheme for youtube app
NSString *youtubeURL = @"youtube://www.youtube.com/user/";

// Page name(or channel name)
NSString *youtubePageName = @"YourPageName";

// Check if the device can open in Youtube app or not.
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [youtubeURL stringByAppendingString:youtubePageName]]]){
    // Open in Youtube app
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [youtubeURL stringByAppendingString:youtubePageName]]];
}else{
    // If device cannot open in youtube app, open the page in browser.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.youtube.com/user/YourPageName"]];
}
```

This solution worked for me

iOS 9 edit: Target app's URL scheme must be added to info.plist under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`key.

Here is a related post: [iOS 9 not opening Instagram app with URL SCHEME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme/30988328#30988328)

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: stopped working in iOS9. It opens app, then redirects to safari

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. In iOS 9 you need to add the URL scheme of the target app that you need to open into your project's plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key.  This post can help you I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme/30988328#30988328

Answer (score 1):

This forum post's lack of responses indicates there probably isn't a way to do this currently: [YouTube iOS URL Scheme for Channels](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/youtube/url%2420scheme/youtube/42DmqMPXHOQ/LfOWjwiHcuEJ)

But you may be able to request that feature on YouTube's iOS app [feedback page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/request.py?contact_type=satisfaction_survey_ios). And in the meantime, I'd recommend just linking to users' HTML YouTube pages.

Comment: There is a URL Scheme for Channels. See my comment in the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, few weeks ago I was looking for the same, but i didn't found anything. Instead I've opted for use a UIWebView to show the youtube channel or using the `openURL:` `UIApplication`'s method to open the channel with Safari.

If you want to save some time, you can use the easy-to-implement TSMiniWebBrowser's control at [this](https://github.com/tonisalae/TSMiniWebBrowser) Github page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the youtube Channel Url scheme, try to load it in UIWebView and it will works.

http://m.youtube.com/#/user/channel_name for e.g http://m.youtube.com/#/user/whartonmagazine