# iOS 9 not opening Instagram app with URL SCHEME

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios9

The following URL opens on iOS 8.3 and lower, but it does not work and iOS 9

```
let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
```

Why won't the URL open?

Comment: What does `+canOpenURL:` return?

Comment: What error are you getting?  This is not a question about [tag:xcode].

Comment: It fails "if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)"  the checking

Comment: Please see the article here: http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes In iOS 9 you must specify what url schemes your app is looking for (I haven't done this myself)

Comment: Add this to your info.plist file       <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>URLScma1</string>
 <string>URLScma2</string>
 <string>URLScma3</string>
</array>

Answer (score 214, accepted):

iOS 9 has made a small change to the handling of URL scheme. You must whitelist the url's that your app will call out to using the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your `Info.plist`.

Please see post here: http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

The main conclusion is that:

> If you call the “canOpenURL” method on a URL that is not in your whitelist, it will return “NO”, even if there is an app installed that has registered to handle this scheme. A “This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxx” syslog entry will appear.
>
> If you call the “openURL” method on a URL that is not in your whitelist, it will fail silently. A “This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxx” syslog entry will appear.

The author also speculates that this is a bug with the OS and Apple will fix this in a subsequent release.

Comment: As a point of clarification, do NOT include "://" in the string of a specific app to be whitelisted in the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array, i.e. "comgooglemaps://". If you do include "://" canOpenUrl: will return NO and provide the "This app is not allowed to query for scheme  xxx" syslog/error. However, when you make the actual call of canOpenUrl: you must still include the colon i.e. canOpenUrl:@"comgooglemaps:".

Comment: Apple did, in fact, fix this in a recent update. `-openURL:` always works even though `-canOpenURL:` is limited.

Comment: What's the point of this? Where is the security if i can just list everything in the plist and still query for it?

Comment: @MaciejSwic One reason is that you can't change the list without resubmitting to Apple.

Comment: Note all of that is related to apps compiled against iOS SDK 9 only. "If you are not recompiling with iOS SDK 9.0, your app is limited to 50 distinct schemes (calls to canOpenURL afterwards return NO)", as specified on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: BTW, the warning of that will still output in log in Simulator.

Comment: @smoothdvd is this still the case? still seeing this in my logs.

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain I think it can be ignored.

Answer (score 169):

As said above, you want to add a key in the info plist, here is the list for most social networks

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
     <string>fb</string>
     <string>fbapi</string>
     <string>fbauth2</string>
     <string>fbshareextension</string>
     <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
     <string>twitter</string>
     <string>viber</string>
     <string>whatsapp</string>
     <string>wechat</string>
     <string>line</string>
     <string>instagram</string>
     <string> instagram-stories</string>
     <string>kakaotalk</string>
     <string>mqq</string>
     <string>vk</string>
     <string>comgooglemaps</string>
     <string>googlephotos</string>
     <string>ha</string>
     <string>yammer</string>
    </array>
```

*
The first 3 match Facebook (FBSDK 4.6): fbapi, fbauth2, fbshareextension. "Ha" is for snapchat

Comment: Thx, I think  v  need to add "fb" to the list

Comment: @sivakrishna fb is not mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: but if i want to redirect to any face book page like "https://www.facebook.com/....",After adding fb only its wrkng

Comment: Almost good. In Octobr 2015 I got some failures with weird URLs from Facebook share dialogs. I added them as an answer, feel free to add it to yours which is indeed correct.

Comment: @ebuild, I am curious, did you have FBSDK 4.6 or an earlier one?

Comment: What is the key for apple maps?

Comment: and `Ha://add/[username]` to add friends snapchat in swift 3

Comment: @Anyone string for yammer?

Comment: @MatthieuRouif ya it opens the app but then it open inapp browser and link is https:// yammer:// and then the app is stuck

Answer (score 86):

This is a new security feature of iOS 9. Watch [WWDC 2015 Session 703](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=703) for more information.

Any app built with SDK 9 needs to provide a `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entry in its plist file, declaring which schemes it attempts to query.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>urlscheme</string>
 <string>urlscheme2</string>
 <string>urlscheme3</string>
 <string>urlscheme4</string>
</array>
```

Comment: To make things clear. Will this rule out such apps that let the user enter their own URL scheme + execute that?

Comment: @Jonny No, because you can still try to open any URL using `openURL:`. And it will tell you if opening was successful or not.

Comment: Yeah but canOpenURL can't be used so we cannot tell the user if it will work or not, he just has to try for himself.

Comment: I want to open google maps what do I have to put in the urlscheme?

Answer (score 27):

Assuming two apps TestA and TestB. TestB wants to query if TestA is installed. "TestA" defines the following URL scheme in its info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>testA</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The second app "TestB" tries to find out if "TestA" is installed by calling:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"TestA://"]];
```

But this will normally return NO in iOS9 because "TestA" needs to be added to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in TestB's info.plist file. This is done by adding the following code to TestB's info.plist file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>TestA</string>
</array>
```

A working implementation can be found here:
https://github.com/gatzsche/LSApplicationQueriesSchemes-Working-Example

Comment: wait, shouldn't be the string value of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key as "testA" in into.plist of TestB app?

Answer (score 23):

From, Session 703 WWDC 2015:

> You can continue to use URL schemes when you build your app for iOS 9
>   and you want to call URL schemes, you will now need to declare them in
>   your apps Info.plist. There is a new key, `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`,
>   and here you will need to add the list of schemes you want to are
>   canOpenURL on.

[image: For instance, incase of FB]

Comment: Yeah, that's not it. It still won't work comgooglemaps, even with the info.plist

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Comment: a picture is worth 1000 words. thanks for the screenshot.  it was all I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook sharing from a share dialog fails even with @Matthieu answer (which is 100% correct for the rest of social URLs). I had to add a set of URL i reversed from Facebook SDK.

```
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
        <string>wechat</string>
        <string>line</string>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>kakaotalk</string>
        <string>mqq</string>
        <string>vk</string>
        <string>comgooglemaps</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>                                                    
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>                                                     
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>                                                    
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>                                                    
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>                                                    
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>                                                     
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>                                                     
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>                                                     
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Do you know which app Can I use to view a document and can you provide me the code for it?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

In info.plist need to add CFBundleURLSchemes and LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

--> Select info.plist in your project,

--> right click,

--> Select **Open As** **Source Code**

See the below screen shot

[image]

--> xml file will be opened

--> copy - paste below code and **replace with your ID's**

CFBundleURLSchemes and LSApplicationQueriesSchemes for gmail, fb, twitter and linked in.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>li5****5</string>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.8***************5f</string>
            <string>fb8***********3</string>
            <string>twitterkit-s***************w</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>8*********3</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>K************ app</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>

    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>twitterauth</string>

    <string>linkedin</string>
    <string>linkedin-sdk2</string>
    <string>linkedin-sdk</string>

</array>
```

See below screen your final **info.plist** file is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that there was a bug with jailbroken phones on 9.0.x which broke url schemes.  If you're running a jailbroken device then make sure you update Patcyh in Cydia

Answer (score 1):

Well you can open an app by calling `openURL:` or `openURL:options:completionHandler:` (iOS 10 onwards) directly without making the conditional check `canOpenURL:`.
Please read the **discussion section** in [Apple doc for canOpenURL: method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl?language=objc) which says:

> the openURL: method is not constrained by the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem anyone has addressed how to specify URLs with embedded parameters. Any URL that contains parameters it won't possible to specify the specific URL in LSApplicationsQueriesSchemes.   For example, assume I have an email app that passes the the senders email address:

```
myemail://mailto?bob@gmail.com
```

The only way it seems to get it to work in iOS9 is to remove any parameters.

Comment: Huh? What you should add in the plist is `myemail`. Parameters play no role here.

Comment: @LeoNatan the subject as in subject="yes you can"

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed the canOpenURL method on iOS 9. Apps which are checking for URL Schemes on iOS 9 and iOS 10 have to declare these Schemes as it is submitted to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

For PayPal add below URL schemes :

[image]

Refer this [link](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-ios-drop-in)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.1, Swift 3.2, Swift 4**

```
if let urlFromStr = URL(string: "instagram://app") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlFromStr) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(urlFromStr, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlFromStr)
        }
    }
}
```

Add these in Info.plist :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score -1):

When I tried to call Facebook from my own app today, I found that there is no a `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key I can add to the `Info.plist` (Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)). I opened the `Info.plist` with **Sublime Text** and manually added it into the file, then it worked. Just to let you know that if you cannot find the key, simply add it yourself.