# How to implement URL Schema in my application?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, url-scheme

I have implement all the required things in my application to enable url schema, and its working fine. I want to open my application from safari. I have pass one URL with parameter like : https://www.myURL.com/signup/callback?signupCode=123?id=20. I want to open my application whenever I press on this link. But its not working.

Please suggest to me what I can do to achieve this. I already added the required tags in the `.plist file` (see below screenshot for reference).

[image: plist infomation]

Comment: Did you implement "- application:openURL:options:" ? ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:options:

Comment: Yes, I do it. I also find it that I have to mplementing Custom URL Schemes, Do you know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.myURL.com/signup/callback?signupCode=123?id=20"]];
```

This is actual code. But hear your link (https://www.myURL.com/signup/callback?signupCode=123?id=20) is not working. So problem is accure.

Comment: I want to open this from safari, Not from my application.

Comment: Yes i know. this link open in safari.

Comment: Yes I know that, this is dummy URL just for you information. But actual URL also not ask for open my application

Comment: You can take reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361655/how-to-open-url-schemes-from-safari-in-ios9