# Open Google Authenticator App

Tags: android, ios, web, google-authenticator

I found out that it is possible to create a new entry in the Google Authenticator App via a link.

Example: `otpauth://totp/Example:alice@google.com?secret=JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP&issuer=Example`

Is it possible to just open the Google Authenticator App on Android and iOS via a link from a website?

If you open the App with a link like this one `otpauth://`, you get an error.

There is a Scheme defined for link in the [iOS](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/blob/bd50d15c348a978c314d2b30e586fbc562096223/mobile/ios/OTPAuth-Info.plist#L42) and [Android](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android/blob/master/AuthenticatorApp/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L47) App

Comment: How are you linking to the custom URL scheme URI? Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33158594/3708242 ?

Comment: Not yet. The app opens, but I think it's expecting a link with content, not empty.

Comment: Yes, if you don't pass in the information in the URI, the app will have nothing to do.  Are you saying you are trying to launch an empty URI: "otpauth://"?  In order to add an entry, you have to provide the full URI with an account, secret and issuer. I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.  You just want to launch the app, not add an entry?

Comment: @wottle Didn't work. The App says `Cannot interpret QR code`. If you click `ok`, you can use the app. But i don't want this error. Yes, i just want to open the app.

Comment: Have you tried the other url scheme: "totp:\\"?

Comment: Yeah. Same error. :(

Comment: In iOS apps, you write code to handle when your app is launched with those custom URL schemes.  Google probably didn't anticipate people trying to use the custom scheme that way, so their code tries to do something with the URI itself, and when empty or invalid, they try to be helpful and provide an error message to tell the user that something is not right. I'm not too familiar with the Authenticator custom scheme, so maybe someone else has figured out how to do this without the error.

Comment: Maybe someone else knows an answer. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Any update on this? I'd like to open the app with otpauth::// url scheme and have the same behavior just like if I would click the app icon.

Comment: No, there are no updates.