# Send Message to user on Whatsapp from app without opening Whatsapp

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

Suppose I have few forms that needs to be filled by the user including contact number. After filling of all the forms, I want that contact number should receive a message including some greetings or some text or image clicked to use in the form. The message should be delivered as a simple SMS and also on WhatsApp. All this needs to be done without opening WhatsApp. Is it possible? If yes then how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be possible.

Yes you can set body of message using 'MFMessageComposeViewController' that involves user-interaction that means without user tapping simple message cant be sent otherwise spams could easily be written.

As far as send message via whatsApp, without opening whatsApp I guess you can only open application

```
NSURL *whatsAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Whatsapp://location?id=1"];

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsAppURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsAppURL]]];
 }
```

Every application has it's Own 'Sandbox' a File System that can not be access outside boundary of that app.

And on iOS 9 you have to add "Whatsapp" under a proper key in your info.plist [iOS 9 not opening Instagram app with URL SCHEME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use UIActivityViewController but you need to customise it for WhatsApp and  there is [open source here](https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity) he prepared everything :)