# How to integrate Skype in my iPhone application

Tags: ios, swift, skype

I am new to **iOS**. I want to integrate Skype in my iPhone application,for this I have searched lot but I have not found a solution for this

How can I get Skype SDK for integration. How can I integrate Skype API in my application. Is there any other way to make developer Skype account

If your people having any sample code please post that.Please help me. Many Thanks.

I have tried some code please see that below but using that code my simulator it's showing alert like below image

### my code:-

```
- (IBAction)skypeMe:(id)sender {

    BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
    if(installed)
    {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
    }

    else
    {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Those are called **URL schemes** in iOS. Official Skype URIs documentation and examples can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745885.aspx and the Skype URI API reference at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx

Answer (score 5):

**For Swift 3.0** It opens itunes url if it is not installed, otherwise it will open skype.

```
@IBAction func btnSkypeLinkPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {

    let installed = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "skype:")! as URL)
    if installed {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "skype:skypeID")! as URL)

    } else {

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8")! as URL)
    }
}
```

and in plist add:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>skype</string>
    </array>
```

Hope it will work for swift users Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your swift code:

**Swift**

```
@IBAction func skypeMe(sender: AnyObject) {

    let installed = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "skype:")!)
    if installed {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "skype:echo123?call")!)

    } else {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8")!)
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (IBAction)skypeMe:(id)sender {

    BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
    if(installed){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
    } else {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8"]];
    }
}
```

I have changed skype `URL` for iTunes in this code and tested it with device and both `URL` is working fine.

Comment: same to you buddy..:) @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Why don't you try this in real device?

Comment: is there any sdk for integrate ios app with skype?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89349/discussion-between-m-v-n-kalyani-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Answer (score 3):

in addition to @Dharmesh's answer, in iOS9 you must add the application you want to query for 'canOpenUrl' to you plist, under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key

see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988328/1787109

Answer (score 0):

Using **Swift 5** you can integrate "one to one" call and also one to many call in skype

```
@IBAction func btnStartSkypeCall(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var installed: Bool? = nil
        if let url = URL(string: "skype:") {
            installed = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
        }
        if installed ?? false {
            if self.mainModelView.eventList!.students?.count ?? 0 <= 1{
                if let url = URL(string: "skype:SkypeID?call&video=true") {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }else if self.mainModelView.eventList!.students?.count ?? 0 > 1{
                if let url = URL(string: "skype:test_skype;test2_skype;test3_skype?call&video=true") {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }else{
                print("Student list is empty")
            }
            
        } else {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skype/id304878510?mt=8") {                 
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"\(url)")!)
            }
        }

    }
```

To start a chat use the schema

```
skype:user?chat
```

To start a video call use

```
skype:user?call&video=true
```

You must be add in plist file

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>skype</string>
    </array>
```