# How can I install a plugin for WKWebView with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, skype

I'm trying to implement web.skype.com in my WKWebView for calling someone. But a message always appears that I have to install a plugin for Skype calls.
I tried to change the user agent but it doesn't work, the message still appears.

My Code:

```
  let url = URL (string: "https://web.skype.com/")
    var requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let userAgent = "Mozilla/10.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_30_2) AppleWebKit/902.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/99.0.2 Safari/902.3.12"
    requestObj.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    webView.configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
    webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webView.configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
    webView.customUserAgent = userAgent

 webView.load(requestObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot install plugins** neither in Safari for iOS (other than [Content Blocking Safari Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ContentBlocker.html)), nor in a `WKWebView`/`UIWebView`.

You should redirect users to the Skype app if you want them to use it for calling. [Here is an answer under another question that addresses that issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44991017/3151675)

Comment: you mean, it doesn't work normally but I can do this by using content blocking extension .Right ?

Comment: @AkifDemirezen No, you cannot use content blocking extensions for calling. I just added that as a note that extensions **do** exist for iOS Safari.