# Instagram sharing not working on iOS 9

Tags: hook, instagram, ios9

This worked fine on iOS 8, but on iOS 9 the UIDocumentInteractionController does appear with the option Copy to Instagram. Pressing it just dismisses the controller.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks,

```
    var docController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
    let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")

    if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
        var imagePost = cropped
        let fullPath = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingString("insta.igo")
        var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePost!)!.writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
        let igImageHookFile = NSURL(string: "file://\(fullPath)")
        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: igImageHookFile!)

        self.docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: self.view, animated: true)

    }

    func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    return documentsFolderPath
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way iOS9 reads it when declaring "insta.igo", now needs to have the "/"

```
let fullPath = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/insta.igo")
```

Complete code

```
var docController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")

if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {
    var imagePost = cropped
    let fullPath = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/insta.igo")
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePost!)!.writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
    let igImageHookFile = NSURL(string: "file://\(fullPath)")
    self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: igImageHookFile!)

    self.docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(rect, inView: self.view, animated: true)

}

func documentsDirectory() -> String {
let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
return documentsFolderPath
```

Comment: Sidenote: The `var docController = UIDocumentInteractionController()` **should be global** for the class/VC, don't put it inside `func`. Try it @noobsmcgoobs.

Comment: @John I cannot thank you enough, your comment should be an answer in its own right, and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provided by **Andy Shephard** worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32616355/1500708