# Titanium appcelerator Platform.canOpenURL and fmp:// url scheme

Tags: ios, appcelerator, filemaker

I asked on appcelerator.com but haven't got an answer and I'm afraid I won't ever. I'm trying my chance here.

`Titanium.Platform.canOpenURL("fmp://~/mydatabase.fmp12")` always returns false even though I can open the url with `Titanium.Platform.openURL`

The fmp url scheme is to launch Filemaker Go.

The function seems to work for other url schemes.

Any idea on how to make the function work or how to check if Filemaker Go has been installed on the phone?

I'm trying to build an app that will launch my Filemaker Go solution. I want it to check if FM GO is installed (if not, the FM GO app store page would be launched).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988328/646960

Comment: That was it. Thanks.