# PFFacebookUtils -

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I'm following [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook) tutorial to integrate facebook login with messenger. When I'm compiling the first part of the code, I receive the error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'`

I came across multiple threads including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727608/pffacebookutils-initializefacebookwithapplicationlaunchoptionslaunchoptions-gi) one, however this was fixed in the new version I'm using already and thus can't be applied to fix my problem.

I hooked up a button that runs the tutorial code:

```
- (IBAction)loginWithFacebook:(id)sender
{
    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!user)
        {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        }
        else if (user.isNew)
        {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    }];
}
```

Also, my AppDelegate.m has:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That guide doesn't mention all of the required code to make it work. Parse does have more info in their [iOS Guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users). To resolve this issue specifically, in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, replace your `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` call with the following:

```
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906178/facebook-sdk-login-throws-error-in-swift-2-ios-9) question. I combined it with Joey's answer and I got it to work.

First, I replaced

`[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];`

with

`[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];`

Then, I went to my info plist and change the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` type from string to array of strings and added item `fbauth2`