# Apps Link not working in facebook and safari

Tags: ios, deep-linking, applinks

I try to implement App Link in my IOS project. I've setup URL Schemes, and tested by typing `testApps://` into mobile safari. Open apps dialog is prompt.

Im also setup a html file, access by public domain, `www.testSite.com/testApps.html` and include basic meta tag recommend by most Apps Link tutorial website. The file is shown as below:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta property="al:ios:url" content="testApps://default" />
       <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="testApps" />
    </head>
</html>
```

However, safari do not prompt to open Apps when i key in the URL.

I also setup facebook apps setting, FB_test_Apps, set URL Scheme Suffix to be `testApps`, turn on **Single sign on** and **Deep Linking**.

I share **www.testSite.com/testApps.html** in facebook, and also from apps which register under facebook apps **FB_test_Apps** (which it will show as "Via FB_test_Apps" under the post).

When i click on this two post, Facebook will load it in facebook's webview. However it do not prompt to open my apps as well.

Is there anything i've missed out?

**Update**

I found out this issue only happen in IOS9. iOS 8 able to work well.

Regard
Steven

Answer (score 2):

Yes iOS 9 has made some changes. You need to whitelist the url schemes you're using in your project. 
Just add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes of type array in your info-plist and mention the urls you need to open in your project under it.

Comment: +1 to you for answering this 10 seconds before I was able to do it.  [More information can be seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme).

Comment: I understand that. but my issue is to open my Apps from Facebook apps. I think in order to do this in IOS9, i need facebook to whitelist my apps. But this is not going to happen isnt it? any thought?

Comment: What are you doing to open your apps from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I guess too late to the party.

As mentioned above by Bhavuk, you have to white list the fb app for iOS9 and up.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
     <string>fb</string>
     <string>fbapi</string>
     <string>fbauth2</string>
     <string>fbshareextension</string>
     <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    </array>
```

Referring from here.

[iOS 9 not opening Instagram app with URL SCHEME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme)