# paypal://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypal

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, paypal

paypal://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypal [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M743c.png)

hey geeting this error while run my app.please review the image

paypal://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypal"

```
2015-11-03 14:42:42.234 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "paypal-local-search://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypal-local-search"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.234 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "halfdotcom://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme halfdotcom"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.235 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "redlaser://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme redlaser"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.236 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "where://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme where"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.236 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebaymotors://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebaymotors"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.237 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb164705030244434://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb164705030244434"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.238 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebayfashion://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebayfashion"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.238 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "stubhub://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme stubhub"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.239 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "sdc://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme sdc"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.239 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb299473330131984://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb299473330131984"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.240 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "paypalhere://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypalhere"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.241 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebaynow://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebaynow"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.241 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cydia://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme cydia"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.242 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "loch://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme loch"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.242 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb1b1cca46cd75ebc75ad67e6904d5f176://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb1b1cca46cd75ebc75ad67e6904d5f176"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.243 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hotspotshield://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme hotspotshield"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.245 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cydia://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme cydia"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.264 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebay://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebay"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.265 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb267453465127://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb267453465127"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.265 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ADX1140://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ADX1140"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.266 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ppclient://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ppclient"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.266 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "paypal://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypal"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.267 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "paypal-local-search://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypal-local-search"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.268 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "halfdotcom://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme halfdotcom"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.268 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "redlaser://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme redlaser"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.269 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "where://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme where"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.269 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebaymotors://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebaymotors"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.270 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb164705030244434://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb164705030244434"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.271 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebayfashion://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebayfashion"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.271 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "stubhub://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme stubhub"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.272 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "sdc://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme sdc"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.273 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb299473330131984://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb299473330131984"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.273 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "paypalhere://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme paypalhere"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.274 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ebaynow://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ebaynow"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.274 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cydia://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme cydia"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.275 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "loch://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme loch"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.276 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb1b1cca46cd75ebc75ad67e6904d5f176://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb1b1cca46cd75ebc75ad67e6904d5f176"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.276 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hotspotshield://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme hotspotshield"
2015-11-03 14:42:42.277 JobGuide[8419:124438] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cydia://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme cydia"
2015-11-03 14:42:44.341 JobGuide[8419:124438] Reachability: Reachable via WiFi
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988328/730701).

Comment: How do we report duplicate comments?  :P

Comment: Refer this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918225/2599596