# Google maps URL scheme not working on iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9.1

The following URL scheme was working on previous version but doesn't work anymore on iOS 9 :

comgooglemaps://?q=Google+Japan,+Minato,+Tokyo,+Japan&center=35.660888,139.73073&zoom=15&views=transit
Did something change on iOS 9 that prevent apps from opening other apps using URL schemes ?

Comment: `App Transport Security Settings` is new in iOS 9 may be it is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think currently you don't add google map scheme to whitelist.

You can reference to this question.
[Whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme)