# CanOpenURL Error occurred, and I'm sure that I made it right

Tags: ios, url, uber-api

Good day everybody.

I'm using "Uber" API in my iOS app, and When I check if `CanOpenURL` it prints `This app is not allowed to query for scheme uber` in the log

I search about it, and I found that I must write this to my `.plist` file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>uber</string>
</array>
```

I did that but also it still the same problem.

Any Help !!

Comment: At one point, this was a known bug with Apple. I don't know if it's been fixed yet. Do some googling to check up on that with Apple. If your app is still working and this is still a confirmed bug with Apple, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this post for more information regarding the behavior of URL schemes in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme) and the bug reported.

Read more about
[iOS deep-linking](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking#section-ios) on Uber.

Also, please consider using the official
[iOS mobile button SDK](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.md) for your deep-links on iOS