# openURL is not working for system schemes on iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, ios9, url-scheme, openurl

`openURL` is not working on iOS 9 for **system** schemes like `http`, `tel`, `telprompt` after compiling via Xcode 7, same code works fine on iOS 8, `canOpenURL` always returns `YES`.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

```
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL]) {

   NSLog(@"canOpenURL");

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:testURL];
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give code, because it works for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme This can help you out. In iOS 9 URL schemes has been changed. You need to add url in your plist.

Comment: @StudentT the code is super clear, please see update

Comment: have you read/heard the news about the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`?

Comment: @holex yes, but after adding this **system** schemes to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` it still doesn't work

Comment: have you read/heard the news about the `NSAppTransportSecurity` on iOS9?

Comment: @holex of course, and now it set as `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>`

Comment: What are you trying to do ? open a safari with the url www.apple.com ?

Comment: @Mr.T exactly, but it also does't work for phone call

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the schemes you open in your `info.plist`.

The key is `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and is an array of scheme names.  Case matters, so match whatever you do in your code.

Comment: It does not matter to system schemes, but after adding this **system** schemes to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, `canOpenURL` always returns `YES`