# iOS9: canOpenURL returning false for WhatApp's url scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, whatsapp, url-scheme

In my current project I need to share text on whatsapp from iOS app.

Here is my code to share text on whatsapp:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

but **canOpenURL** always returning false in iOS9.

Is there any iOS9 privacy policy?
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: with iOS 9, Apple Transport Security was introduced. Maybe it has something to do with it. It basically says you can´t send any unsecure requests anymore. But I´m not sure if it is the problem in this case.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme

Comment: ATS has nothing to do with this.  Apple introduced a separate system which requires stating in `info.plist` which schemes an app will use, but it's completely orthogonal to ATS.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In iOS 9 you must whitelist any URL schemes your App wants to query in Info.plist under the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key (an array of strings):

For example:

[image]

So in your case, instead of `fb` and `twitter` you will have to specify `whatsapp`.

Note that this mechanism only applies to canOpenURL and not openURL. You do not need to have a scheme listed in Info.plist to be able to open it with openURL.

Comment: @MayankModi Glad to help :)

Comment: For the lazy ones: here is the code for your plist (add it at the end of the main dict node): `<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @z22's answer if you need to add it textually (e.g. with Xamarin) then it looks like this:

```
    <dict>
        ... 

        <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>whatsapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step:1 Add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in Info.plist

Step:2 Add whatsapp in items

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was because I was using **URL types** instead of **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**

and it work only for **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**

This will **not work**

[image: URL types]

This will **work**

[image: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes]

Answer (score 1):

for someone who still finding this issue, its because **canOpenURL** is **abuse to check all installed app**. use **Open** instead and wait for async result.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {success in
            if !success { self.screen?.showToast(message: "App not installed")}
        })
```