# React Native Linking.canOpenURL() with WhatsApp call

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking, whatsapp

I'm trying to create a link to start a conversation on whatsapp from my react native app, but the method Linking.canOpenURL() is allways retuning false...

My code is the following:

```
const url = `whatsapp://send?phone=${celNumber}`;
Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(url);
    } else {
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert',
            'WhatsApp is not installed',
        )
    }
});
```

If I try to put some other url like `tel:${celNumber}` it returns true, so I think there is some problem with whatsapp url and canOpenURL(), since the whatsapp url works with the method Linking.openURL()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quess you are using iOS?
Then you have to declared the URL’s scheme 'whatsapp' in your Info.plist file LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

[iOS9: canOpenURL returning false for WhatApp's url scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329595/ios9-canopenurl-returning-false-for-whatapps-url-scheme)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl