# Share an URL on LinkedIn from an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linkedin-api

I am developing a iOS app in that I need to share URL on linkedIn When user taps share button my app's URL should be shared. If the LinkedIn app is installed sharing should be via app and if app is not installed user should be able to share vis safari.Below is my code

```
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://shareArticle/mini=true&url=http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629"]]) {

        // opening the app didn't work - let's open Safari
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629"]]) {

            // nothing works - perhaps we're not only
            NSLog(@"LinkedIn doesn't works. Punt.");
        }
    }
```

This is working perfectly fine when the app is not installed user is redirected to safari and my app's URL is included. 
But if the app is installed it opens the share pop-up but don't include my URL. Sharing is working fine 
I need to include the URL to the share that I am passing.

Comment: If you're building and iOS9 app, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme

Comment: @LucaD thanks for the reply. I am running the app in iOS 8.4. I am able to open the linkenIn share pop-up in the native app  but this pop-up not having any URL that I am passing . app and share pop-up is opening but the URL I am passing is not passed to the share pop-up

Comment: @NeerajPathak Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete refrence guide is here
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: Nothing on there about URL schemes though.