# Youtube application launch from other app is not working in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, ios9

```
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VideoID"]]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VideoID"]];
    }
```

Output :
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFccvtrP1d8" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme youtube"

Comment: Why do you want to check for `canOpenURL`? Just open the url.

Comment: I need to open only in youtube app.Could You help on this?  I want to do other cases on else part

Comment: Weather it is working on ios 9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme you basically have to whitelist the youtube scheme

Comment: are you added the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your plist

Comment: what i want to add on LSApplicationQueriesSchemes for Youtube, That is my real problem now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

> In iOS 9 you must whitelist any URL schemes your App wants to query in Info.plist under the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key (an array of strings):

add string as `youtube`

for example

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>youtube</string>
   </array>
```

> secondary check that the youtube app is available or not in your device

for example

```
 NSString *Name = @"VideoID";

NSURL *linkToApp = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://watch?v=%@",Name]]; // I dont know excatly this one 
NSURL *linkToWeb = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",Name]]; // this is correct


if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToApp]) {
    // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToApp];
}
else{
    // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWeb];
}
```

for more information about play [**Youtube Video**](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#YouTube)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (xCode 14.2) you will need to add "Queried URL Schemes" with "youtube" as one of its items on info.plist.

[image: Nowadays you will need to add "Queried URL Schemes" with "YouTube" as one of the items]