# How can I open the link on an application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink

I added a code for Xcode from the internet.

This one:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
```

It took me to www.youtube.com on the Safari browser, what if I have youtube application? how can it open that from the application in my iPhone?

p.s I’m a newbie

Comment: You should look into URL Schemes. Those can be used to open a specific app

Comment: see this link it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963222/youtube-application-launch-from-other-app-is-not-working-in-ios-9

Comment: Try the code I have updated for you.

Comment: kb920 and Black Magic, thank you .... Anbu.Karthik - thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)btnYoutube:(id)sender {

    NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://user/%@",@"toyotaleasing"]];
    NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/%@",@"toyotaleasing"]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
        // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
    }
    else{
        // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yours also worked
Thank you!

Comment: I have one question!
If I got a URL which was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls .. what should I add in your code? I'm getting a threat!

Comment: Do you have only one url to show or there can be multiple urls. I mean you only want to show this video or it can be any video ? You have to format your url as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: This is the only URL to show!

Comment: Even when I remove it all, I still have a thread.

Comment: Replace 1st two lines of my method with these two lines.

Comment: Try this: 
`NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls"]; `

`NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls"];`

Comment: This one : Unused variable 'linkToAppURL' and this one :Unused variable 'linkToWebURL'

Comment: `NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls"]; NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
        // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
    }
    else{
        // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
    }`

Comment: you declared the variable but you aren't using them for opening app

Comment: I removed everything for the link, it shows me the same problem on the button :(

Comment: Removed everything means? Code is still there in the answer

Comment: Yes but I still have a problem when I removed the like http://oi66.tinypic.com/261f22g.jpg

Comment: This is SIGABRT. I can't see your code.

Comment: I removed the button and made another one, it works well, the thing is, I don't know what to change in the brown ones, in the very first code, my iPhone works fine but .. what if it was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls?

Comment: In the two thngs @"youtube://user/%@",@"toyotaleasing" @"http://www.youtube.com/user/%@",@"toyotaleasing I don't know what to add!

Comment: I can't msg there but it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Use URL scheme for youtube : **youtube://**

Eg.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video-id>"]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video-id>"]];
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.