# navigate to default musicplayer from my application

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to navigate to music-player of iPhone from my application in iOS using objective-c?

Comment: What do you mean "navigate" ? Open Music.app ? Have controls to do next/previous/pause ?

Comment: yes i want to open  default music player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]]) 
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]];
```

for `iOS9` you need to integrate the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `.plist` also , ref this [link once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the AVAudioPlayer utility Framework:

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can open apps from your app by using `iphone URL Schemes`.

```
NSString *stringURL = @"music:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Check this [Iphone_URL_Scheme](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) post for more details. it have great explanation to how to open app from own app.

Hope this will help :)