# Quick Match of Google Play Game RealTime Multiplayer creating error in log on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, google-play-games, multiplayer

I'm implementing real Time Multiplayer by using Google Play Game Service.
and running my code in iphone6 simulator on cocos2d-x.

All my errors are showing in CCLOG:

When i pressed SignedIn Button then the error is :
error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlechrome"

When i pressed QuickMatch Button then the error is :
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

after signedIn successfully with google signIn ,
when i checked for isSignedIn then it is returning
Not signedIn but in reality i'm signedIn already.

I want to create a QuickMatch between two Players.

Answer (score 0):

This error 'This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlechrome' means that you didn't add scheme to your app's `.plist` file. You might also need to add to the plist another key called [LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) and add the 'itms-books' scheme to it as a string item, to allow the canOpenURL to test against it. Note that it is better if you try run it on an actual device.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>xxx</string>
</array>
```

Based from this [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme) iOS 9 has made a small change to the handling of URL scheme. You must whitelist the url's that your app will call out to using the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in your Info.plist.

> The main conclusion is that if you call the `canOpenURL` method on a URL that is not in your whitelist, it will return `NO`, even if there is an app installed that has registered to handle this scheme. A `This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxx` syslog entry will appear.
>
> If you call the `openURL` method on a URL that is not in your whitelist, it will fail silently. A `This app is not allowed to query for scheme xxx` syslog entry will appear.