# Sending Whatsapp message to a specific contact number (Swift Project)

Tags: swift, url, social-networking, whatsapp

I'm trying to send a whatsapp message to a recipient number stored in a global variable!

By using this simple code:

```
let whatsAppUrl = NSURL(string: "whatsapp:\(globalPhone)")
            
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsAppUrl as! URL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsAppUrl as! URL)
} else {
    let errorAlert = UIAlertView(
        title: "Sorry",
        message: "You can't send a message to this number",
        delegate: self,
        cancelButtonTitle:"Ok"
    )
    errorAlert.show()
}
```

I'm always getting the alert message which's the else case!
although the number is always true!
May be the the error in the url syntax?

In the console:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "whatsapp:0534260282" -
"This app is not allowed to query for scheme whatsapp"
```

Is this the correct way to do that?
Or this way just for sharing, text through Whatsapp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues.

The first is that's not a valid url scheme. A URL scheme takes the format `identifier://params` so you'll need to use `whatsapp://phone_number` instead.

Secondly is that Apple now requires you to define which external url schemes that your application uses in your Info.plist file, nested under the key LSApplicationQueriesSchemes. Please see [iOS 9 not opening Instagram app with URL SCHEME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987986/ios-9-not-opening-instagram-app-with-url-scheme) for more info.

---

According to the Whatsapp URL scheme docs, you can't actually supply the phone number of the contact that you'd like to send the message to: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013.

You can however supply the message that you'd like to send to them:

`whatsapp://send?text=Some%20Text`.

Ensure that the text is percentage encoded as otherwise NSURL will fail to create a valid URL from the supplied string.

Comment: I have did this! But I could open the whatsapp application only not to the recipient I want to send the message to?

Comment: How can I make it direct to the recipient?

Comment: @Mariah it doesn't seem like that's possible, according to their docs: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013, you can however specify the text. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Is there any character limit?

Comment: Can i send a message to more than one number

Answer (score 13):

Try this....

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?phone=***********&text=***"

var characterSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
characterSet.insert(charactersIn: "?&")
  
if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSet){
                   
if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
    } else {
        print("Install Whatsapp")
                           
    }
}
```

> Note:Country code (Ex:+91) is mandatory to open mobile number Chat

Note: Add url scheme in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Thanks, it has worked for me to send a text directly to a certain number

Comment: is there any chances of app rejection due to send direct to user

Comment: @SangramShivankar  No , there is no issue in app store review.

Comment: Hi, Can I send the message to multiple Phone Numbers

Comment: this is not working anymore, whatsapp open and show error "The link couldn't be opened check the link and try again."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send to a **specific** number use the folowing code:

```
let whatsAppUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=**********&text=******")
    
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsAppUrl as! URL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsAppUrl as! URL)
} else {
    let errorAlert = UIAlertView(
        title: "Sorry",
        message: "You can't send a message to this number",
        delegate: self,
        cancelButtonTitle:"Ok"
    )
    errorAlert.show()
}
```

The trick works because you don't call **directly** whatsapp, but the browser, and this one can receive the number of phone and open whatsapp to desired phone and desired text

Comment: Can i send a single message to more than one number

Comment: @shubhammishra AS far I now is not possible, but you can simply iterate foreach phone number by sending the same message

Comment: Thanks bro, but I do have to handle the next iteration call on the success of the first one since, Calling openURL() inside for loop will leads to open WhatsApp multiple times and will end up by opening chat screen for the last number. So, basically can I have closure or any kind of callbacks after openURL(). If u find the solution please add it into your answer.

Comment: this is not working anymore, whatsapp open and show error "The link couldn't be opened check the link and try again."