# iOS: Sharing image in social network Swift

Tags: swift, instagram, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

I am running sample app in swift. I need to share image from my app. 
With the help of `Social framework` , I integrated `Facebook` and `Twitter`. Now I dont know how to integrate with `Instagram` and `WhatsApp`

**Share Button Action**

```
  @IBAction func shareAcn(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    var documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

    let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("smc", ofType: "png")
    documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL!))
    documentController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
 }
```

**WhatsApp**

```
 @IBAction func shareAcn(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   var documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController!
   let image = UIImage(named: "smc")
   let filename = "myimage.wai"
   let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, false)[0] as NSString
   let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/" + filename)
   UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!.writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: false)
   let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: destinationPath) as NSURL
   documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(URL: fileURL)
   documentController.UTI = "net.whatsapp.image"
   documentController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
 }
```

If I select [Import to WhatsApp or Copy to WhatsApp] app getting crashed. If I select `WhatsApp`, "This Item Cannot Send".

**Instagram**

```
var instagramURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://user?username=USERNAME")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramURL)
}
```

None of code is working.

I installed `Instagram` and logged as my user in my testing device and if I run, `Instagram` is not opening.

I dont know how to solve this? Kindly guide me.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30988328/1457385

Comment: LSApplicationsQueriesSchemes  ?? Where is it in Info.plist ? I cant find it out.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your if statement does it ever hit it?

Comment: else part is always working ??

Comment: @shallowThought if u knw the answer pls let me knw ? I am serchin every where..but not understood concept.. pls

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you have set the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entries in the `info.plist` file, declaring which schemes it attempts to query.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>  
<array>  
     <string>whatsapp</string>
     <string>instagram</string>  
</array>
```

Do not include "://".

If you do include "://" canOpenUrl: will return NO. When you make the actual call of canOpenUrl: you must still include the colon i.e. `canOpenUrl:@"instagram:"`

You can find more information in [this WWDC 2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/).

---

Also, this line is suspicious:

```
var instagramURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://user?username=USERNAME")
```

I suspect you did copy this from [Instagrams documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/). If so, replace `USERNAME`with your actual username.

---

To isolate the error, you might want to try a simpler URL first:

```
var instagramURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
```